# htaccess URL rewrite page.php?page=string containing a hyphen

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a solution for my redirect problem. In `.htaccess` file I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) category.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And this is working for a query like 
`category.php?page=pinturas` and redirect to `category/pinturas`.

But, if the string have `-` like this:
`category.php?page=aquoso-madeira` it redirects to `category/aquoso`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `category.php?page=aquoso-madeira` It redirect to `category/aquoso`

Because your `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not include the hyphen (`-`), so it matches everything up to, but excluding, the first hyphen.

Include the hyphen in the character class:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) category.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Note that the hyphen (`-`) must go at the start or end of the character class, since this is a special character and has alternative meaning when used elsewhere.

> And this working for query like category.php?page=pinturas and redirect to category/pinturas

Note that this *rewrite* does the complete opposite of what you are describing.

This rule takes a request like `category/pinturas` and internally rewrites it to `category.php?page=pinturas`. (There is no external *redirect* here - which might be in another part of your code?)